# Should I recompile class implementation when non virtual function changes to virtual function?

Tags: c++, virtual-functions, vtable, binary-compatibility, memory-layout

I have a old static library(class implement), I'd like to change a non virtual function to virtual function in a class, should I recompile the library?

Comment: Added [tag:vtable] because the vtable layout is affected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wanted to add little more reasoning to answer of @jesper
Yes because now there will be new entry per new virtual function in vtable so recompilation is must.

Comment: *And* because all calls to it will now have to go via the VFT.

Comment: yes! VFT will be looked up by every call to object to this class.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You *must* recompile the library *and* applications using it.